# Porting some code from ruby openssl to java

Tags: java, ruby, openssl

I have the following:

```
def from_code(code, secret)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::BF.new
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(secret)
  data = cipher.update(Base64.decode64(code + "\n"))
  final = cipher.final
  plaintext = data + final
  plaintext
end
```

and my goal is to achieve the exact same using commons.binary and javax.crypto (or whatever other dependency, that's fine), but in Java only. I'm messing around with javax.crypto but thought I would ask here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you could execute your ruby code from within java: https://github.com/phoet/ruby-java-jruby-rjb

Comment: the issue is the openssl dependency. it is difficult to get that gem available to my process, otherwise I'd be fine using jruby

Comment: https://github.com/jruby/jruby-ossl doesn't work?

Comment: Azolo: it works fine, but I need to use this code in an existing Java project, and do not know how to package a jruby gem to depend on within a Java project.